# Pop index falls out of range despise decrementing a copy of the original list

Tags: python, list

This has been an ongoing issue.  I'm trying to see that if a given list is a strictly increasing sequence if I remove no more than one element from the list.  This is my attempt:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    new_seq = sequence.copy()

    output = False

    for i in range(len(sequence) - 1):
        new_seq.pop(i)
        if all(i < j for i, j in zip(new_seq, new_seq[1:])):
            output = True
        else:
            output = False

    return output
```

As you can see, I'm creating a copy of the original array to not alter its length and I'm still getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  main.py3 in the pre-written template, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _runkkown(testInputs[i])
  main.py3 in the pre-written template, in _runkkown
    return almostIncreasingSequence(*_fArgs_bfjukyininyb)
  main.py3 on line 7, in almostIncreasingSequence
    new_seq.pop(i)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve? You're iterating **UP** a range of integers, whilst using `pop` to remove one element from the list. Eventually, dependant on the size of your list, `i` will be greater than `len(new_seq)`, this throws an index out of range error.

Comment: At each run of the for loop, I want to take the original `sequence` array and pop element i out of it to see if the remaining array is a strictly increasing sequence.

Comment: Do you want a `true/false` for every iteration? Or are you wanting it to iterate until it cannot go any further, then output the `true/false`?

Comment: You *are* altering the `list`, here: `new_seq.pop(i)`, and since your range is based on the initial length of that sequence, `pop(i)` will eventually be out of bounds. Note, you are *not* working with arrays, but with lists.

Comment: @PacketLoss I want to iterate until it cannot go any further, then output the true/false?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I think this is practically a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382), can you explain what you’re trying to do, your overarching goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a check of `new_seq` to ensure you're not attempting to pop an `index` that does not exist. We can use `len()` for this, then you can continue your checks after to return a result.

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    new_seq = sequence.copy()

    output = False

    for i in range(len(sequence) - 1): 

        if len(new_seq) > i: # If we can pop, we pop.
            new_seq.pop(i)
        else: # Else if we can no longer pop without causing an error, we perform our check and output the result
            if all(i < j for i, j in zip(new_seq, new_seq[1:])):
                return True
            else:
                return False


lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(almostIncreasingSequence(lis))

#True
```

Comment: I think it's not right prove it with for example `[1,5,2,3]` which is an almost increasing sequence

Comment: The code was to fix the issue he was encountering, the list was an example, as it seems the issue was more to do with the process of popping from the list. If there are further issues i can update answer to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this? The list will be monotone (removing at least 1 element) if is equal to the ordered list!

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        new_seq = sequence.copy()
        del new_seq[i]
        not_sorted = new_seq.copy()
        new_seq.sort()
        if new_seq == not_sorted:
           return True
    return False
```